# Code to convert Unicode to ASCII

Tags: c++

I am looking for code for convert unicode to 7bit ASCII. Any suggestions?

Comment: Unicode is 16/32 bit - making it 7 bit is not decompression - it's compression.

Comment: If you were to call it compression then it's lossy compression, at best.

Comment: Do you need to "decompress" it, or do you want functions to print it and play with it?

Comment: Unicode is actually 20 bits; UTF-16 is a 16 bits encoding and UTF-32 a (trivial) 32 bits encoding.

Comment: yes i need function to decompress it in c++

Comment: Woah, did this whole question change over night?

Comment: Rolled back to the original question.  @dweep - click on the Ask Question link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask to ask a new question.

Comment: Is writing "thanks" all that much more difficult than writing "thanx"?

Comment: Also, does using punctuations cost any money? And btw, is hello/thanks needed in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

If encoded with utf-8, it is the same for both ascii and unicode as ascii is a subset of unicode. See the example in [RFC 2044](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2044.html)

Answer (score 0):

A simple example below:

```
        try
        {
            System.IO.TextWriter writeFile = new StreamWriter("c:\\textwriter.txt",false,Encoding.UTF7);
            writeFile.WriteLine("example text here");
            writeFile.Flush();
            writeFile.Close();
            writeFile = null;
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: This allows you to write to UTF-7, the string can be in any encoding i believe

Comment: NOTE: If there are some characters in the string that is not supppored by UTF-7, it will be lost

Comment: Looks rather more Java than C++ to me.

Comment: @Kylotan, I was thinking it looked more like C#, but same point: OP wanted a C++ answer.

Comment: @Xander: UTF-7 is a Unicode encoding, like the UTF-16 used by .Net. Now there are characters outside of Unicode (Klingon for instance) but you can't lose those by converting between different Unicode representations.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to adapt the code from glib C function [`g_str_to_ascii()`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-String-Utility-Functions.html#g-str-to-ascii) to C++:

[Link to `g_str_to_ascii()` code](https://github.com/GNOME/glib/blob/master/glib/gtranslit.c#L330)